# Comparing each property to the same value

Tags: c#, datetime, interval

My code keeps some `int` value about the date range, and there is a method to check if all of it is zero. Is there a better way to do it than doing this?

```
public bool IsAllDayZero
{
    get
    {
        return
            Today == 0 &&
            Days1_2 == 0 &&
            Days3_6 == 0 &&
            Days7_10 == 0 &&
            Days11_15 == 0 &&
            Days16_30 == 0 &&
            Days31_45 == 0 &&
            Days46_60 == 0 &&
            Days60Plus == 0
            ;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is: *Why do you want to change it*?

I bet you can get a shorter form with some use of *xor*, *and*, *or* etc. functions but I believe it's not worth it. For example:

```
public bool IsAllDayZero
{
    get
    {
        return
            (Today | Days1_2 | Days3_6| Days7_10 | Days11_15 |
             Days16_30 |  Days31_45 | Days46_60 | Days60Plus) == 0;                
        }
}
```

It's indeed shorter but no way that it's more clear for some other person about what this code tries to achieve.

Or you can get a faster version that will revert the conditions and then execute only few conditions without a need to check them all but again I doubt that clarity of the code will worth such a changes.

However your current implementation is clear, complete and does exactly what it has to do without some extra noise and I just recommend not to change it.

Comment: Maybe having `return (Today + Days1_2 + Days3_6 + Days7_10 + Days11_15 + Days16_30 +  Days31_45 + Days46_60 + Days60Plus) == 0;` would make it a little more clear to other people.

Comment: @Piers. It would be clear but not correct - we need to think about overflow in this case. If I try to write the sum of two bytes (1 and 255) into byte field the result will be 0;

Comment: yeah, you're probably right. As you stated, the current implementation is fine and is probably how I would have done it, plus `&&` is a short-circuit operator in C# and will stop evaluating subsequent conditions as soon as one becomes false.

Answer (score 2):

I see 3 alternative solutions:

1. Use array of `days`, and then: `days.All(d => d == 0)`
2. You can define boolean variable `areAllDayZero` or something else :-) and change it when you set values to properties
3. Use reflection